# Comparing two lists then assigning if element equal

Tags: c#, list

Hi guys I am trying to compare two lists which both vary in size but if one list contain the same as the other list I want that particular element to be set to a differant object.

```
        for (int i = StartItemIdx; i < EndItemIdx; i++)
        {
             TmpOrderItem = mIOrder.mCurrentOrderItems[i];

             //more code follows within this loop
        }
```

I have another list called 'temp' which is the same type as 'mIOrder.mCurrentOrderItems' what I am after happening is for each element found in 'temp' TmpOrderItem will equal it. but somehow need mIOrder.mCurrentOrderItems[i] to do it.

So in other words I need to check the elements in 'mIOrder.mCurrentOrderItems' against the ones in 'temp' checking if any of them are equal and then somehow attach it to the above.

```
    for (int i = StartItemIdx; i < EndItemIdx; i++)
    {
         TmpOrderItem = temp[i]; // is basically what I want but with the first example used

         //more code follows within this loop
    }
```

Ive tried just doing:

```
    for (int i = StartItemIdx; i < EndItemIdx; i++)
    {
         if(mIOrder.mCurrentOrderItems[i] == temp[i])
              TmpOrderItem = mIOrder.mCurrentOrderItems[i];
         else break;

         //more code follows within this loop
    }
```

but because they at most times have a differant size I get the out of range expection.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Linq is your friend. Use `Intersect` method, if start index and end index is important you can use `Skip` and `Take` methods to make sure you're working in particular range.

```
var intersections = mIOrder.mCurrentOrderItems.Intersect(temp);
foreach (var item in intersections)
{
    //Do whatever with item
}
```

Comment: Thanks! Hasnt solved the issue i am having but answered my question :)

Answer (score -1):

you can linq intersect to merge both list.
here is an example in this webpage http://www.dotnetlines.com/Blogs/tabid/85/EntryId/47/Using-Intersect-method-of-LINQ-to-retrieve-common-elements-from-two-arrays.aspx

Comment: Not my downvote, while the link may answer the question it is recommended to add essential part of code in your answer itself as links may go dead.

Comment: Not yet my downvote: Link only answer should be comment (and you have privileges to do so already)... OR to make good answer make sure to provide complete sample with small summary inline (in addition to link).